# Restangular does not give back the objects coming from REST api

Tags: javascript, json, rest, asp.net-web-api, restangular

I would like to ask some help.
I have a service can be called using the `domain/service/webapi/` url. When the `domain/service/webapi/menu/getmenucategory` then it gives back the JSON string below which represents the menu structure of the application:

My issue is that if I call this url using restangular then I got and empty object back. However, Fiddler says that Restangular calls the webapi service and it gives back the json below. I don't understand why restangular does not give back the javascript objects I expect.

I went through the documentation, but I haven't found anything. I assume I did something very simple thing wrong.

Here are the scripts:

Controller:

```
'use strict';

dilibApp.controller('NavigationMenuController', function ($scope, navigationMenuService) {

    $scope.menuCategories = navigationMenuService.GetMenuCategories();

});
```

Service:

```
'use strict';

dilibApp.factory('navigationMenuService', function(Restangular) {

    return {
        GetMenuCategories: function() {
            //var menuCategories = Restangular.all('menu', 'getmenucategory');
            var menuCategories = Restangular.all('menu/getmenucategory');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(menuCategories.getList()));
            return menuCategories.getList();
        }
    }
});
```

Result in Chrome Console:

```
 {"restangularCollection":true,"$object":[]}
```

JSON string:

```
[{"$id":"1",
"Id":1,
"Name":"File",
"SortNo":0,
"IsEnabled":1,
"MenuItems":[{"$id":"2",
        "Id":1,
        "Name":"File menu item 1",
        "IsEnabled":1},
        {"$id":"3",
        "Id":2,
        "Name":"File menu item 2",
        "IsEnabled":1}]},
{"$id":"4",
"Id":2,
"Name":"Administration",
"SortNo":1,
"IsEnabled":1,
"MenuItems":[{"$id":"5",
        "Id":4,
        "Name":"Administration menu item 1",
        "IsEnabled":1},
        {"$id":"6",
        "Id":5,
        "Name":"Administration menu item 2",
        "IsEnabled":1}]},
{"$id":"7",
"Id":3,
"Name":"Modules",
"SortNo":2,
"IsEnabled":1,
"MenuItems":[{"$id":"8",
        "Id":6,
        "Name":"Modules menu item 1",
        "IsEnabled":1},
        {"$id":"9",
        "Id":7,
        "Name":"Modules menu item 2",
        "IsEnabled":1}]}]
```

Comment: Ok, I wanted to do something against - it seems to me - Restangular concept. I moved my Restangular calls into the controller and it is working fine now, however, I don't like having the server calls and the controller functions in the same method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because RestAngular is returning a promise. So you have to do something like:

```
$scope.menuCategories = [];
navigationMenuService.GetMenuCategories().then(function(result){
     $scope.menuCategories = result;
});
```

You problem is that if you directly assign then you are just getting the promise object and since it is async the immediate result in that array is an empty one at first. Until the promise completes and then the array would have the result in it.